# Dynamic polygon size for sculpted area

Tags: sculpting, dynamic-topology

When sculpting with "Dynamic Topology", is it possible for the polygon size to change depending on the size of the sculpted area? Basically, I want the polygon size to change the same way it does in Sculptris. Very often I find it difficult and time consuming to change the Constant size manually and Sculptris just makes that sweet balance between appearance and performance automatically so you can focus on sculpting only. Is that possible in Blender somehow? Or maybe some add-on of some sort? I wanted to use Sculptris for sculpting, but it has some missing stuff that I like so much like more brushes etc.. and import- export between the two programs so many times is anoying.

Comment: I am not experienced in scupting, but i think there is a need for a discussion for people who have experience with different software, analyze weak and strong point, and come up with a proposal to developers for a better tool.

Comment: I agree. Well, that kind of stuff is happening on the "Blender Artists" forum, but I don't really know how that site works, so I asked here since I think this question deserves to be asked here too hah.

Comment: You can open a chat room dedicated to that subject, its in the top left corner, click on the StackExchange logo.

Comment: I usually use chat rooms only when I extend the discussion with too many comments. Thanks :)